# Dragging in JEdit and Ubuntu may lockup cursor and make desktop access impossible

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, jedit

EDIT: probably not a jEdit bug.. This is the one way I know to re-create the problem.

Environment: Gnome, Ubuntu 14.04, jEdit from the repository, OpenJDK

On occasion when performing a click, hold, and drag over selected text, jEdit will go into some mode with the mouse pointer.  It turns into a no-drop sign (circle with a line through it).

EDIT: to re-create the problem, drag some text to a no-drop zone (like the line number margin or the buffer list), press ESC to cancel except keep the left-mouse drag button pressed, finally move the mouse a little more maybe 1px in the no-drop zone and see if you can get the no-drop mouse pointer to come back again.  If you do, congratulations!!! your screwed (you'll probably be stuck now)... Now, fast pressing of ESC or perhaps a r-click in the no-drop zone and more fast pressing of ESC can get you out.

Another way out is to switch to a tty terminal `Alt+Ctrl+F1` and locate and `kill (jedit pid)`.

Any idea what this "feature" is called?  It is important to know more about it, killing jedit will loose information like ones place withing files.  If one does not know the tricks to get out of it, it is necessary to reset the computer.

Comment: I cannot imagine this as jEdit problem to be honest. I've never heard of something similar and never have seen such behavior, and I use jEdit on Ubuntu on a daily basis. What version do you use? Do you use the official version from us, from our own repository? Or do you use the version from the Ubuntu sources? If the latter, then who knows what Ubuntu guys did, they often modify the software they add to the official repositories.

Comment: Version 5.1.0+dfsg-1, Ubuntu 14.04, yes it is from the repository.  Your correct, very unlikely that the OpenJDK was given that kind of power over the desktop and less likely that jedit has a bug with that.  It is one way to re-produce the problem though.  I drag stuff around for days before one goes bad.

Comment: I have two mice plugged in but I'm only moving one at a time.

Comment: Are you using Gnome desktop or KDE?   Have you tried a different desktop to see if the problem still manifests?  That might help figure out what part of the system is having issues.